# Scrolling down with JS script in python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

So, I am trying to scroll down till a certain text appears using the following code, however as soon as I go to page the driver quits, with the following code.

```
def scroll_wait():
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    find_elem = None
    scroll_from = 0
    scroll_limit = 3000
    while not find_elem:
        sleep(2)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(%d, %d);" % (scroll_from, scroll_from + scroll_limit))
        scroll_from += scroll_limit
        try:
            find_elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='uiHeaderTitle']")))

       except TimeoutException:
           pass
    driver.close()
```

I'm also trying with the following `XPATH`, but it just keeps on scrolling even after the text,

```
(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'More About You')]")
```

And this is the HTML code for the text I am trying to scroll to.

```
 <h3 class="uiHeaderTitle">More About You</h3>
```

Comment: For Selenium, one good way to test is build a plain HTML page that only contains what you want (For example, a h3) and mimic the scenario. I don't really know your problem but one changes that you can try is `presence_of_element_located` will return true if it is in the DOM, that means it is not necessary visible, this might be the reason for it to quit immediately. Try changing to `visibility_of_element_located`

Comment: @AngYC that works really good, you might as well post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Selenium, one good way to test is build a plain HTML page that only contains what you want (For example, a h3) and mimic the scenario. I don't really know your problem but one changes that you can try is `presence_of_element_located` will return true if it is in the DOM, that means it is not necessary visible, this might be the reason for it to quit immediately. Try changing to `visibility_of_element_located`

Hope it helps!